# d3 choropleth map colors

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'm trying to recreate the map shown [here](https://s23.postimg.org/47evvful7/fertility_rates_in_europe_2013.png) using D3 but I'm having trouble binning the values from my data and mapping them to colors. Currently I'm using scale.quantile that I believe sets the number of bins according to the range which should be 8 since I have 8 colors. So it would bin up the fertility values into 8 different bins and map each bin to each color but the colors are incorrect. In my data Sweden has a fertility rate of 1.89 and Russia 1.7 but they are the same color on my map which looks like [this](https://s27.postimg.org/63lk9uyar/map1.png) with my current code. What am I doing wrong?

```
        var width5 = 700;
        var height5 = 500;

        buckets = 8,

        colors = ['#ff1a1a','#ff471a','#ffd633','#ffff1a','#ccff33',' #66ff66','#00ff00',' #009900'];


        var projection = d3.geo.mercator()
                               .center([ 13, 52 ])
                               .translate([ width5/2.5, height5/1.7 ])
                               .scale([ width5/1.5 ]);

        var path = d3.geo.path()
                         .projection(projection);


        var mapchart = d3.select("#mapchartarea")
                    .append("svg")
                    .attr("width", width5)
                    .attr("height", height5);

        d3.json("data/europe_geo_fertility.json", function(error,collection) {
            if(error) throw error;

            console.log(d3.min(collection.features, function(d) { return d.properties.fertility;}))

            // Sets color for each country according to fertility rate
            var colorScale = d3.scale.quantile()
                .domain([0, buckets -1, d3.max(collection.features, function(d) { return d.properties.fertility;})])
                .range(colors);

            // Draws Map
            mapchart.selectAll("path")
               .data(collection.features)
               .enter()
               .append("path")
               .attr("d", path)
               .attr("stroke", "rgba(8, 81, 156, 0.2)")
               .attr("fill", "rgba(8, 81, 156, 0.6)")
               .style("fill", function(d) { return colorScale(d.properties.fertility); });

            // Adds name of each country
            mapchart.selectAll("text")
            .data(collection.features)
            .enter()
            .append("svg:text")
            .text(function(d){
                return d.properties.name;
            })
            .attr("x", function(d){
                return path.centroid(d)[0];
            })
            .attr("y", function(d){
                return  path.centroid(d)[1];
            })
            .attr("text-anchor","middle")
            .attr('font-size','6pt');                  

        });
```

[image]

Comment: Is it that the domain starts at 0 instead of at the minimum fertility rate? e.g. `.domain(d3.min(...), d3.max(...))`

Comment: Reading up on the `quantile` scale ( http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10579944/how-does-d3-scale-quantile-work ) I don't think the values you have in there `[0, 7, d3.max(...)]` are correct. Have you tried a linear scale with just the `d3.min` and `d3.max` values as the domain?

Comment: its works finally! I changed it to d3.scale.quantile().domain([d3.min(..), d3.max(..); Thanks!